# In which cases avplayer should play? Like play() function, set player rate

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem

I set player to pause and i am setting player rate after the pause. After setting player rate `avplayer` starting the playing without `play()` method, so i want to know in which other cases that `avplayer` should play without `play()` method.

I find that when we set `rate` or seek to specific time than it is play but i want to know is there other cases when `avplayer` should play.

Comment: Probably not, but you surely cannot be surprised.

Comment: Is there any other cases you know?

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: You can try to pause() player and next line change the player rate. It will play.

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://github.com/teamSolutionAnalysts/sa-plug-avplayer which is very easy plug and play module, lets you play video easily and you tube embedded url supported.